# Why is index 6 out of bounds in the for loop?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I try to check if one of the 2 conditions is true and if it is the case write a string from array "arr_string[]" to a new array "arr_new_string[]" and "arr_bool[] to a new array "arr_new_bool[]".

```
//@version=5
indicator("TEST", overlay=true)

var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 3, 6, frame_width=1, border_width=1, border_color=#0d14ec)

a = false
b = true
c = false
d = true
e = false
f = true
g = false
h = true
j = false
k = true
l = false
m = true

arr_bool = array.from(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, k, l, m)
arr_new_bool = array.new_bool(0)

arr_string = array.from('test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3', 'test 4', 'test 5', 'test 6')
arr_new_string = array.new_string(0)


for i = 0 to array.size(arr_bool) - 1 by 2
    if array.get(arr_bool, i) or array.get(arr_bool, i + 1)
        array.push(arr_new_string, array.get(arr_string, i)), array.push(arr_new_bool, array.get(arr_bool, i))

if barstate.islast
    if array.size(arr_new_string) > 0
        for i = 0 to array.size(arr_new_string) - 1
            table.cell(tbl, 0, i, text=str.tostring(array.get(arr_new_string, i)) + ' ' + str.tostring(array.get(arr_new_bool , i)), text_color=color.white, bgcolor=#0d14ec)
```

Why is index 6 out of bounds because I'm getting this error?

Error on bar 0: In array.get() function. Index 6 is out of bounds, array size is 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two arrays:

```
arr_bool = array.from(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, k, l, m)  // Length: 12
arr_string = array.from('test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3', 'test 4', 'test 5', 'test 6') // Length: 6
```

And then, in the `for` loop you are trying to read from both with the index of `i`.

```
array.get(arr_string, i)
array.get(arr_bool, i))
```

Length of `arr_string` is 12 and length of `arr_bool` is 6. Since arrays are zero indexed, 6 is out of bounds for `arr_bool`. That's what the error message is telling you.

`i` in the for loop becomes 6 and even higher. You cannot use `i` to read from `arr_bool` without additional checks.

Comment: Ok thanks, is the arr_string array looped 2 by 2 too?